# How would I pin a .jar file to the taskbar in Unity Display

Tags: java, taskbar

How would I make it so that I can run a .jar file from the task bar on the side in Unity. As it is I cannot drop a .jar file onto it.

How would I create something that I could pin to the Task bar that would link into running the .jar. Just in case you need to know I am trying to put minecraft onto the task bar and I cannot seem to correctly make a desktop file to link to it.

Answer (score 1):

The command you need to put into your .desktop file should look like

```
java -jar /path/to/minecraft.jar
```